# When I exit SSH session bitcoind goes down

Tags: bitcoind

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

I've tested several scripts that try to get bitcoind running on startup but none have worked out for me.

I'm getting a little bit desperate because I can't even get bitcoind running once I exit my SSH session.

Any clues on how to get bitcoind running once I exit the SSH session?

Best Regards,

Comment: `bitcoind -daemon`? Otherwise, what version of bitcoind are you using, and what do you see in debug.log?

Comment: the last line of debug.log. addcon thread interrupt
opencon thread interrupt
msghand thread interrupt
dumpaddr thread stop
Flush(false)
DBFlush(false) ended               0ms
StopNode()
net thread interrupt
ERROR: CAddrman::Write() : open failed
Flushed 11563 addresses to peers.dat  37ms

Comment: I tried to run with bitcoind -daemon but onde I exit the SSH session the bitcoind stops

Comment: @André how do you know it stops?

Comment: @Loour, when I telnet the host on 8332 not answer anymore. If I enter again the shell is not running anymore. I've also discovered that when I run "bitcoind -daemon &" the process goes to the pid(example) 12994, but one minute later the pid is on 12995. For this reason when I close the SSH this pid go away. Any clues?

Comment: @André Maybe try rebuilding the packages? I really don't know though. Just doing `bitcoind -daemon` has always worked for me. It might also be something with the computer. Does it exit out of other shell scripts when you disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

You could use screen or a similar tool like tmux or byoblu. 
Otherwise use the NOHUP command.

nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.
Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.
nohup is a low-level utility simply configuring a command to ignore a signal. As seen below, nohup is very far from being a full-featured batch system solving all the problems of running programs asynchronously.

> $ nohup abcd &
>
> $ exit

Alternatives:
The screen or tmux command can also detach a process from the current shell. It allows to reattach to the process later on.
e.g. the following call will run somescript.sh detached from SIGHUP and in the background:

> $ screen -A -m -d -S somename ./somescript.sh &

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

My advice is to learn to use screen (or tmux) so you can later re-attach the process to the main shell and interact with it.